# json generated by rails can't be recognized by react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I have a react componente like this

```
var Task = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="task" id={ this.props.task.uid }>
        <div className="header">
          <span>task #{ this.props.task.uid }</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
});
```

and when a task is created, I add this task to the task list inside an `create.js.erb`

```
<% if @task.errors.any? %>
  $("#error-alert").removeClass('hidden')
<% else %>
  $('#task-modal').modal('hide')
  $('#tasks-list').prepend(React.renderToString(Task({ task: '<%= @task.to_react %>' })))
<% end %>
```

turns out that when the task component is prepended, he is prepended empty (just a box, without any text).
I tried `<%= @task.to_react.to_json.html_safe %>` and also had no success

My `Task#to_react` method:

```
def to_react
   {
     role: role,
     need: need,
     result: result,
     uid: uid
   }
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that familiar with rails but unless it's doing some magic here you're embedding the object in a string.

Try

task: <%= ... %>

Instead of:

task: '<%= ... %>'